# Issue with AdmobFree - Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, admob

I am getting the following error when I try to build my Ionic 2/Angular 2 project:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        return AdSize.SEARCH;
^
        symbol:   variable SEARCH
        location: class AdSize

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
        > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or
        --debug option to get more log output.
```

Hope anyone can help me.
 I use the following plugin:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-free/

Thanks!

Edit:
I am guessing that the problem is:

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;

so for some reason my ionic project doesn't get google libraries correctly :(

Comment: Solved! I did run "android sdk" and after updating the libs everything is working.

This thread can be closed